# Correct json to call addConfigurationProfile method by using a SoftLayer REST API

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Please tell me correct json to call addConfigurationProfile method by using a SoftLayer REST API. I tried it in the following way, but it did not work.

```
curl -K support -d @aaa.json -X POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent/addConfigurationProfile
```

When executing the command, the following error message is displayed:

> {"error":"The property 'agentId' is not valid for
>   'SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent_Configuration_ValueArray'.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

The contents of the JSON file are described below:

```
{
    "parameters": [{
        "agentId": 4994537,
        "configurationDefinitionId": 34073,
        "description": "",
        "profileId": 192407,
        "id": 89150443,
        "value": "88"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following json template:

```
curl -K support -d @aaa.json -X POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent/$agentId/addConfigurationProfile

{  
    "parameters":[  
        [  
            {  
                "agentId":4994537,
                "configurationDefinitionId":34073,
                "profileId":192407,
                "value":"88"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well the fist thing I can see is that you are missing the init parameter:

see documentation:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent/addConfigurationProfile

It says that the init parameter is required.

See this documenation:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/REST

so you need to add that in your request

```
curl -K support -d @aaa.json -X POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent/$MonitoringAgentID/addConfigurationProfile

Note: Replace $MonitoringAgentID with the id of the monitor agent that you want to change
```

Also in documentation it says that it needs "configurationValues" as parameter as you can see this is in plural so the method is expecting an array and not a single value.

Regards